# Detail band with borders in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have to encapsulate header column, detail and page footer bands (column footer is set to 0 height) with borders. Is there an easy way to do it?

I've read this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193235/how-to-draw-a-border-around-both-the-column-header-footer-and-detail-sections) and I try to use a frame in the background band, but how can I know the exact height of the detail band?

**UPDATE:** I found myself a solution. The solution is to "trial and error", setting random frame height until I get the exact height.

Answer (score 1):

In the report inspector on the left click on "Detail 1" and then on the right in properties it'll tell you the 'Band Height'...You can change it from there.

Comment: Yes, I know, but my report is an A4 letter in PDF so my detail band, in design mode, is only the size of a row of fields.