# Take sensitive frame with height of detail row

Tags: jasper-reports

I try to border my bands in this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193235/how-to-draw-a-border-around-both-the-column-header-footer-and-detail-sections):

But I have a text field of my row detail with property `isStretchWithOverflow="true"`

In this way when I try to print my report, on the rows with overflowed text field, I've a discontinue on my border (white space instead draw line of frame).

[image: Example of my detail band]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple.

I've added this property `stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"` on my frame object.

So the line has not discontinuity.